# REST Data Souce not showing any data

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, rest

I am trying to use a REST data source, by following [this article](http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2010/04/sp2010-rest-data-sources-within-sharepoint-designer/).
I create the data source, but when I insert it as a data view web part, nothing happens.

If I enter just the path to the service in the browser (e.g. http://servename/subsite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc), I am able to load the XML list of lists and libraries, but if I add /Listname at the end, nothing loads.

What am I missing? In [this article](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/12/28/got-rest-querying-sharepoint-list-data-using-rest-services-client-side-part-1-aspx-2/) it says that you can view the items in XML format, but they don't load for me.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the user token in your current scope, I do suggest using API instead of SVC. There your endpoint should looks like :

```
/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('MyListNameWithOrWithoutUrlEncode')/Items
```

This way, presuming you are using a GET Method, you can test endpoint into browser, to check whole syntax. This is a powerfull tool, as you can filter, sort and expand in a single call.

```
/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('MyListNameWithOrWithoutUrlEncode')/Items?$select=Id,Title,Editor/ID,Editor/Name&$filter=Editor eq 1&$expand=Editor/ID,Editor/Name
```

[More about REST syntaxe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Have you noticed the question is tagged "SharePoint 2010"? Have you read the question?

Comment: My fault... Sory to waste your time